Why am I getting an INDEX SKIP SCAN?
Scenario is as follows:
Table T is created as of
CREATE TABLE T
(
    f_a ...
    ,f_b ...
    ,f_c ...
    ,ctv  NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL
    ,ffc  DATE NOT NULL
    ,v    NUMBER(1,0)
    ,uc   NUMBER(1,0)
    ,...
)
PARTITION    BY RANGE(ffc) INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
(
    PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN ( TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00') 
)

And let there be the local index
CREATE INDEX I_01 ON T(ffc,v,ctv) LOCAL;

When I query as in
SELECT /*+ INDEX(a,I_01) */ 
       *
FROM   T a
WHERE  (a.ctv=10 OR a.ctv=13 OR a.ctv>20)
       AND a.v   =  1
       AND a.ffc >= TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')

I get an INDEX SKIP SCAN.
Questions are:

Why INDEX SKIP SCAN, if the local index covers the partition prefix, and I am consuming every pieze of the prefix of the index?
How can I modify the INDEX to get an INDEX RANGE SCAN?
Notably, If I remove the ctv and the v conditions from the WHERE, and I keep only the ffc conditions, then I get an INDEX RANGE SCAN.

Note: I added a hint because otherwise, the optimizer would perform a FULL SCAN (to avoid the INDEX SKIP SCAN, I suppose)
